# Facebook login using ParseFacebookUtils not working in release android apk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Develop an app in which "Login with Facebook" is present. I properly configured the fb logic flow during app development and successfully tested on debug version.

Now after signing my apk and place keyhash @fb developer account and parse website. "Login with Facebook" is not working on release apk. I double check all the keys and not able to figure out what's goes wrong?

Facebook always return null ParseUser in release apk.

If someone face this issue earlier please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are logging user in you receive two parameters in callback: `ParseUser` and `ParseException`. You can check it and see what is wrong.

Please be more specific in the future as it is really hard to help you now.

Comment: Thanks SeCorp. I already checked that expection. I am not getting any error from parse side. ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(final ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException err) { if(user==null){Log.d("sucess","success") else if(user.isNew()){ Log.d("sucess","1")}} });

Comment: facebook always return user = null hence always I got success in Log.

Comment: You are not supposed to check User because it's not useful at all. You have to check ParseException `Log.d("PARSE", err.toString());`. It should have message when user is null.

Comment: Thanks SeCorp. I am getting this error com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: The supplied Facebook session token is expired or invalid.

Comment: Can you please help me in resolving this issue because i don't find any lead or reference

Comment: Make sure you set your Facebook App ID and secret correctly in Parse dashboard and you have Facebook App ID configured in your app.

Comment: Thanks SeCorp. I found out the mistake in parse dashboard i mistakenly put keyhash instead of app secret. Thanks Again.